# Jinja2 printing for loop onto one line, separated by a character

Tags: templates, jinja2

I currently have something like this:

```
{% set task_names = [] %}
{% for items in payload %}
    {% set task_names = task_names + [items.task_name] %}
{% endfor %}
{{ task_names|join(' >> ') }}
```

which returns a blank. No error. Just a blank.

I would like an output to be:

```
# in python list syntax
task_names[0] >> task_names[1] >> task_names[2]
```

So essentially, printing the items of the list onto one line, joined together by ">>"

Answer (score 0):

Figured most of it out with:

```
{% set task_names = [] %}
{% for items in payload %}
    {% set task_names = task_names.append(items.task_name) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ task_names|join(" >> ") }}
```